# Circles from Page View Controller iOS 7

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I have created a Page View Controller. I can load the content view controller with the array to load the Page View Controller (code below). But in the content view, the controller doesn't load the "circles" to scroll pages. What is the problem?

```
// Create page view controller
self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CondicionPageViewController"];
self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

NMCondicionPageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

// Change the size of page view controller
self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 50);

[self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your page view controller's data source and implement the method 
`presentationCountForPageViewController:`. In that method you will return the count for the number of dots you want.

You're also probably going to want to implement 
`presentationIndexForPageViewController:` to return the index for which dot you want highlighted.

Comment: Hi Adam. Yes...I have implemented this method (below) but not show the scroll circles. - (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return [self.listaPicos count];
}